# Changing app type from iPhone to Universal in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

I have submitted an iPhone app to Apple. It was rejected because it did not run on an iPad. I traced the problem to iAds and have fixed it. Now however, I find that the iAds do not appear on the iPad (that has been reported on a different question here). I can fix all this by making the app universal. 
My problem is that, having submitted the app as an iPhone app, I can find no way to change it to a universal app in iTunes connect. I could delete the app and resubmit, but as I believe I would have to use a different name. Having made a significant investment in the current name, I very much want to avoid this. Is there a way round this?

Comment: You just upload it as normal. Assuming you have set the correct device in your target settings, ITC will identify this and set it up for you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just change the device setting in xCode and upload to iTunes Connect, remember to also add screenshots for the new device!